# pyglet - loading/blitting image with alpha

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I'm trying to make a simple application with pyglet. My main problem so far is that I can't seem to blit an image with alpha - all of the transparent pixels are converted into black pixels. I'm not sure whether the problem is with the loading of the image or the blitting. Here is a very basic overview of how I'm trying to render the image:

```
import pyglet
import pyglet.clock

window = pyglet.window.Window()

window.config.alpha_size = 8

#fancy text
text = pyglet.resource.image("text.png")

#background image
bg = pyglet.resource.image("bg.png")

bg.blit(0, 0)
text.blit(100, 100)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You most likely just need to enable GL ALPHA blends.

```
from pyglet.gl import *
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

But first of all, your code is not able to run.
Mostly because you don't declare a `window.event` function to handle the `on_draw` where you normally render things.

Secondly, you never clear your window (which will cause a mess).

Here's a minimal working example of your code:

```
import pyglet
import pyglet.clock

window = pyglet.window.Window()

window.config.alpha_size = 8

#fancy text
text = pyglet.resource.image("text.png")

#background image
bg = pyglet.resource.image("bg.png")

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

    bg.blit(0, 0)
    text.blit(100, 100)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Now this generates this:

[image]

And here's a working example of how you use the GL_BLEND feature:

```
import pyglet
import pyglet.clock
from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window()

window.config.alpha_size = 8

#fancy text
text = pyglet.resource.image("text.png")

#background image
bg = pyglet.resource.image("bg.png")

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    glEnable(GL_BLEND)

    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
    bg.blit(0, 0)
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
    text.blit(100, 100)

pyglet.app.run()
```

This yields a result like so:

[image]

However, this code will quickly become messy.
So there's two things you can do. You can first, put your images into sprite objects. Secondly, make this a bit more object oriented.

First, we'll use sprites.

```
self.fancy_background = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('bg.png'))
self.fancy_background.draw()  # not blit!
```

Sprites automatically uses transparency, which makes your life (and code) a lot easier.

Secondly, we'll put these into a batch.
Batches are made to bunch A LOT of sprites so you can call `.draw()` on the batch, and all sprites in that batch gets insta-rendered.

```
self.background = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
self.fancy_background = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('bg.png'), batch=self.background)
self.background.draw() # background, not fancy_background! And also not blit!!
```

Last and most certainly not least.
We'll put this into a class so we can do cool stuff later on.

```
import pyglet
import pyglet.clock
from pyglet.gl import *

key = pyglet.window.key

class main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__ (self, width=800, height=600, fps=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(main, self).__init__(width, height, *args, **kwargs)
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0

        self.background = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.texts = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

        self.fancy_background = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('bg.png'), batch=self.background)
        self.fancy_text = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('text.png'), batch=self.texts)

        self.mouse_x = 0
        self.mouse_y = 0
        self.alive = 1

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        self.mouse_x = x
        self.mouse_y = y

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        if button == 1: # Left click
            pass

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0

    def render(self):
        self.clear()

        self.background.draw()
        self.texts.draw()

        self.flip()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = main()
    x.run()
```

[image]

BAM.

This code will enable you to create custom functions and custom "player objects" later on for instance. Also you can do collision detection easier and the code just looks a lot more structured (I threw in a little bonus features such as keyboard and mouse events).

Note tho, that the position of the sprites will default to `x=0, y=0` as shown in the last picture. You can set the position with `x=100` either on the variable/handle or when creating the sprite.

Comment: As I said, I put a VERY simplified version of the code I was using. I know how to create applications in python, been doing this for years. You didnt have to put all the extra info, but thanks for doing it anyway. Definite upvote.

Comment: @nousername Missed that it was a simplified version. But even then, it would be neat if it was minimized to a version that at least was able to run :) Lastly, others might end up here (quite a common topic) so I thought it was better to leave a thorough answer. Cheers for the upvote and best of luck with your project :D

Comment: @Torxed I'm one of the others, and I really appreciate that you pointed out the qualities of sprites that make them appropriate for this use case. Even as an experienced dev, I'm new at pyglet and found this extremely helpful.

Comment: Glad to hear @JamesM.Lay! :D Just remember, as soon as you plan on going 3D, sprites become pretty obsolete in most usecases since they don't scale to well. But in cases such as UI design, 2D games etc, they're pretty useful :)

Comment: @Torxed A small note, you do not have to set `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` and `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` every time when drawing (inside the `@window.event` -> `def on_draw`). It is only needed to be specified once, I would suggest at the top.

Comment: @WilliamR. Totally correct, I've thought about changing it like 10 times haha. It's a pretty old answer tho, but I'll change it in a few min :)

Comment: @Torxed Just wanted to point that out if maximum performance is required. Yeah, I just had the same issue as him (user:5294702 aka nousername?), and figured if it only where needed to be set once, and found out it did. Really great answer btw.